# Preserving the Custom Number Format when using read_excel() then converting to CSV with to_csv() with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a simple script that converts Excel files to CSV using Pandas. Here's the gist of my code:

```
read_file = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
read_file.to_csv(csv_file, index=None, header=True, float_format='%.0f')
```

However, my issue is that the Excel file has several columns with dates, and the output in the CSV file is with the cell's literal value with the format mm/dd/yyyy. On the Excel file, a Custom Number Format has been applied to convert the dates to mmm yyyy format (e.g. 01/01/2001 becomes Jan 2001).

I want to convert the Excel to CSV and have the date values stay in its Custom Number Format rather than the literal value in the cell. Is this possible?

P.S. I know about adding a `date_format` in `to_csv()`, but I'd prefer keeping the Custom Number Format as this tool is going to be used in a number of different Excel files that may or may not contain their own Custom Number Formats. That's why I'm having a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering cell value using number format is a function of Excel. I think pandas and openpyxl only know the information of the table, such as the value and number format, but do not know how to render cell value according to the number format.

If we wanted to, we can render the value as a string based on the number format, just like Excel. We can get the number format of the cell through openpyxl.

```
import openpyxl
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
sheet = workbook[workbook.sheetnames[0]]
print(sheet.cell(2,1).number_format)
```